# Use HTMLPurifier to append a class name to CSS styles written in CKEditor

Tags: css, ckeditor, htmlpurifier

In CKEditor, I'm writing custom CSS like:

```
a {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

but I don't want it to overwrite my css written for other global components of my project. Is there a way to use HTMLPurifier to add a class to all my css written in CKEditor. Something like:

```
.my-ckeditor-class a {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

In my purifier.php file I have this rule set up but I'm not sure how to go about prefixing a class to all CSS written in my CKEditor

````
'ckeditor' => [
         'HTML.Allowed' => 'b,i,u,a[href|title|target|style],ul,li,br,ol,p,em,strong,img[alt|src|style|width|height],table,td,th,tr,iframe[src|width|height|frameborder]',
         'Attr.AllowedFrameTargets' => [ '_blank', '_top', '_self', '_parent' ],
         'CSS.Trusted' => true,
         'CSS.AllowedProperties'    => 'display,font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,padding-right,padding-top,padding-bottom,padding,margin,margin-left,margin-right,margin-top,margin-bottom,color,background-color,text-align,vertical-align,background-image,background-position,max-width,width,height,max-height',
         'HTML.MaxImgLength'   => NULL,
         'CSS.MaxImgLength'   => NULL,
         'CSS.AllowTricky' => true,
         'CSS.AllowImportant' => true,
         "HTML.SafeIframe"          => 'true',
         "URI.SafeIframeRegexp"     => "%^(.*)%",
         'CSS.[something-to-prefix-class]' => [
             'class'  => '.my-ckeditor-class',
         ]
     ],
 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `Filter.ExtractStyleBlocks.Scope`:

> If you would like users to be able to define external stylesheets, but
> only allow them to specify CSS declarations for a specific node and
> prevent them from fiddling with other elements, use this directive. It
> accepts any valid CSS selector, and **will prepend this to any CSS
> declaration extracted from the document. For example, if this
> directive is set to #user-content and a user uses the selector
> a:hover, the final selector will be #user-content a:hover.**
>
> The comma shorthand may be used; consider the above example, with
> #user-content, #user-content2, the final selector will be #user-content a:hover, #user-content2 a:hover.

But keep this warning in mind (although I don't know if this is still relevant, this is a pretty old warning at this point):

> Warning: It is possible for users to bypass this measure using a
> naughty `+` selector. This is a bug in CSS Tidy 1.3, not HTML Purifier,
> and I am working to get it fixed. Until then, HTML Purifier performs a
> basic check to prevent this.

If you want to use this directive, check out the other `Filter.ExtractStyleBlocks` directives in [the configuration documentation](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Filter.ExtractStyleBlocks.Escaping), they're meant to be used together (or at least assessed together).